# How to change Angular components at runtime in root component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I want to add a dynamic form. When the configuration button is pressed, the form should change from `app-login-form`to the `login-config-form`.

app.component.html

```
<div class="container p-5">
  <app-login-header></app-login-header>
  <div class="load-form">
    <login-config-form></login-config-form> 
    <app-login-form></app-login-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {
  Component,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try that:

```
<div class="container p-5">
  <app-login-header></app-login-header>
  <div class="load-form">
    <button (click)="displayConfig = !displayConfig">Toggle</button>

    <!-- If is displayConfig then show login-config -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="displayConfig; else isLoginForm;">
      <login-config-form></login-config-form>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- else show isLoginForm -->
    <ng-template #isLoginForm>
      <app-login-form></app-login-form>
    </ng-template>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<div class="container p-5">
  <app-login-header></app-login-header>
  <div class="load-form">
    <button (click)="displayConfig = !displayConfig">Toggle</button>
    <login-config-form *ngIf="displayConfig"></login-config-form> 
    <app-login-form> *ngIf="!displayConfig"</app-login-form>
  </div>
</div>
```

TS:

```
//...
export class AppComponent {
   public displayConfig: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Is there no better way? Something like `<template #form></template>` and my AppComponent controlls the form to load.